# IOS Core Location framework did'nt work out on ios 4.2 simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, gps

IOS Core Location framework did'nt work out on ios 4.2 simulator.Anybody knows the issues.Any one a have ios 4.2 working code for getting current location.

Thanks,
VKS

Comment: could you give some more information as far as in what way it didn't work? Perhaps a description of your specific problem?  Are you looking for solutions or only confirmation from other people having the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simulator always gives you default fixed location in Cupertino... For thorough testing of Core Location apps in simulator you can use following library:
https://github.com/futuretap/FTLocationSimulator

Answer (score 1):

U cannot test CoreLocation framework in simulator. U have to test it with device.