# "Access to Location Services denied by user" - CLLocationManager

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, cllocationmanager

I'm writing an application which uses CLLocationManager to collect GPS data. Not long ago my simulator began sending me exceptions like kCLErrorDenied without asking confirmation to get the GPS data. Who knows how to fix this trouble?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot test CoreLocation framework in simulator. For more details, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761781/ios-core-location-framework-didnt-work-out-on-ios-4-2-simulator/6761883#6761883).

Comment: Yes, you're right! I can't explain why I need that. Earlier I always get window with asking "Alloy the application to get GPS data?". Now I always get kCLErrorDenied  error in this app. In another app all works good. How can I fix this trouble in my app?)) Screen: http://rghost.ru/15719231.view